# AWS S3 generating heaps of requests

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I am learning Amazon S3, CloudFront, Route 53 at the moment.

I currently host a simple single page React app on Amazon S3 with CloudFront as the CDN and most files (except index.html) are set "Cache-Control: max-age one year".

I have a domain 'www.markz-employer-tracker.net' and I use Route 53 as DNS to route traffic to a CloudFront distribution. The CloudFront distribution then decides whether it wants to get files from S3 bucket or not based on the Cache-Control header of files and whether there are new files in the S3 bucket.

The website basically has no traffic or maybe less than 10 accesses per day.

I run a circle ci pipeline that removes all built files and pushes the newly built files onto S3 on master branch change. However it runs only for fewer than 5 times a month.

This is the github link to the website: https://github.com/MarkZhuVUW/ts-react-s3-circleci-employer-tracker

I am trying to understand why AWS Budget tells me at the start of the month that there have already been 18535 requests on the S3 bucket given that I use CloudFront to cache most files and the traffic is not very significant.

screenshots here:
[AWS Budget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URt1W.jpg)

Comment: Did you enable health checks on R53?

Comment: you can turn on AWS Cost Explorer and see which S3 API was being called the most.